# Where to save files in iPhone app? Library/ vs Application Support/, and subdirectory vs non-subdirectory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to save files of user settings of my iPhone app in ~/Library/ directory.
I don't want to use ~/Documents/ directory because I don't want users to see or modify the files in iTunes using the file sharing feature.

But there are 4 choices to save files in ~/Library/:

**1. ~/Library/some-data.plist**
This uses Library/ directory without creating a subdirectory in it.
(The API constant name is NSLibraryDirectory)

**2. ~/Library/MyAppName/some-data.plist**
This uses Library/ directory and a subdirectory which name is my app's name.

**3. ~/Library/Application Support/some-data.plist**
This uses Application Support/ directory without creating a subdirectory in it.
(The API constant name is NSApplicationSupportDirectory)

**4. ~/Library/Application Support/MyAppName/some-data.plist**
This uses Application Support/ directory and a subdirectory which name is my app's name.

**Questions**

What are the merits and demerits of the each path above?
And where do you save your app's data in Library/?

Should I use ~/Library/ or ~/Library/Application Support/?

Should I create a subdirectory or shouldn't I create it?
If I should create a subdirectory, is it a good practice to use my app's name for the subdirectory?
Or is there better names for the subdirectory?

Comment: You need to read Apple's documentation. Things to consider are also what gets backed up to iTunes, so you should read it all carefully and make the right decision for each individual file.

Comment: @gnasher729 thanks for the comment. I already read the documentation. The documentation says all of the directories in my question are backed up to iTunes and they are not deleted by app's update process. But the answer to my question is not written in the documentation. And some people suggest using the path 1 or 2 which is shown in my question but some people suggest using 3 or 4. Please tell me the differences of the 4 paths, if you know about it.

Answer (score 2):

From: [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Put app-created support files in the Library/Application support/ directory. In general, this directory includes files that the app uses to run but that should remain hidden from the user. This directory can also include data files, configuration files, templates and modified versions of resources loaded from the app bundle.